# Javascript- fixed header on scroll using Materialize, small jump

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, materialize, sticky

I have followed this tutorial on W3schools to create a fixed header on scroll. So the navbar starts at the bottom of the page, and upon scrolling once the navbar reaches the top of the page, it sticks there.

[W3Schools How to Create a Fixed Header on scroll](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sticky_header.asp)

I successfully implemented these instructions from W3schools with the Materialize side navigation menu, meant to be used with the Materialize Scrollspy effect. It is working great so far except for two issues I can't seem to figure out.

1. Once the navigation menu reaches the top of the screen and it transitions to being sticky, there is a very small jump in it's position. I have altered some settings, but I can't seem to stop that jump. Why is it happening and how can I make it appear smooth?
2. When I use Scrollspy to scroll to a different section of the site, and then refresh the page, the side navigation menu disappears until I start scrolling the page again. I am using  window.onscroll, so I am guessing that is why it's happening. But I notice it does not happen with the W3Schools example, so I'm wondering if I have something set up wrong?

Here is a link to my portfolio website where I'm having these issues:

[My portfolio website.](https://jennifer0101.github.io/Jennifer-Faye-Portfolio/)

Here is the code:

```js
// execute navFunction on scroll
window.onscroll = function(){navFunction()};

// get navbar
const navBar = document.getElementById("contents-wrapper");
  
// get offset position of navbar
const sticky = navBar.offsetTop;

// reach scroll position - add sticky, leave scroll position - remove sticky
function navFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navBar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navBar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
#contents-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  float: right;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 77.5%;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
   <!--Parallax-->
    <div class="parallax-container z-depth-1 hide-on-small-only" style="height: 650px">
        <div class="parallax"><img src="assets/images/flower.jpg"></div>
        <div class="overlay1">I'm Jennifer Faye</div>
        <div class="overlay2">A full stack web developer with an eye for design.</div>
    </div>
    <div id="pic-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col s12 m4 l2">
                    <img id="jen" class="z-depth-1 circle" src="assets/images/Jen.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="col s12 m4 l8">
                    <p id="blurb">I am passionate about developing well designed websites; both aesthetically,
                        and with attention to user experience and mobile responsiveness.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col s12 m4 l2">
                    <!--table of contents pinned navigation-->
                    <div id="contents-wrapper">
                        <div class="col hide-on-small-only m3 l2">
                            <ul class="section table-of-contents">
                                <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                                <li><a href="https://docs.google.com/document/d/1s9vhyk3Z4IUGwLp1fxUAPLAbVsfRia0cHx67qVqZRKE/edit?usp=sharing"
                                    target="_blank">Resume</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: if by jump you mean the nav moves slightly, this is because the left position you give it when it's sticky is not the same as it's left position when unstuck. You might want to calculate its left position on page load, then use that for the sticky. As for the other issue - you could wrap the scroll in a function that checks if the page has been scrolled, then apply the sticky class if so.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem of the little jump. I had float it to the left instead of to the right, then I made the grid l1 instead of l2. Works perfectly now. I'm still trying to figure out the other issue though.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this seems to have solved my second issue:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(this).scrollTop(0);
});
```